# Excel formula to check a text value from a cell against table's first column and return a value from the table second column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

excel formula: Formula in column B (cell B1, B2, ...) must check if a word from C1:C4 is used in A1 and return a corresponding value from D1:D4.

In result, the column B should look like below. This is an example of input data and results in the column B.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Go 2 steps | M | Jump | J |
| Turn left | T | Go | M |
| Jump fence | J | Turn | T |
| Run forward | M | Run | M |
| Turn around | T |  |  |
| Go 5 steps | M |  |  |

I have done that some time ago using INDEX, MATCH AND VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP but can't find it any-more. I remember that it took me long time to make it work. If a cell in column A is empty, corresponding cell in column B stays clear.

Comment: In this case, since it's always the first word, you could use VLOOKUP: `=VLOOKUP(LEFT($A$1:$A$6;FIND(" ";$A$1:$A$6)-1);$C$1:$D$4;2;0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LOOKUP()` function to accomplish the desired output in column `B`

[image]

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(SEARCH($C$1:$C$4,A1)),$D$1:$D$4)
```

And Fill Down for the rest of the cells.

---

**Edit: 3/2/2024**

With Modern Versions of Excel Using `TEXTBEFORE()` & `VLOOKUP()`

[image]

---

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(A1:A6," "),C1:D4,2,0)
```

---

Comment: Thank you! I only had to change commas into ; I have different settings in my language.

Comment: Sounds Good, that it got resolved =)